# Получить изображение в файл из видеопотока

Tags: c++, opencv

Не удается получить изображение с вебкамеры в отдельный файл. На выходе не получается совсем никаких файлов в папке, где ожидались фотографии.
Пробовал менять разрешение, менять камеры, использовать `IplImage` вместо `Mat` если использовать `IplImage`, получается абсолютно серое изображение.

```
void ShowCam(int CameraToBeOpened)
{
int i = 0;
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap(CameraToBeOpened);
cvNamedWindow("Camera", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
while (true) {
    if (cap.read(frame))
        imshow("Camera", frame);
    char c = cvWaitKey(50);
    if (c == 27)
        break;
    if (c == 32) {
        char filename[200];
        sprintf_s(filename, "\Test pictures\test_%d.jpg", i);
        i++;
        cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
        std::cout << "Image has been captured" << std::endl;
    }
}
cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

Comment: А вы вообще попадаете в ветку с `cv::imwrite` перед тем как проверять наличие результата в папке?

Comment: Да, конечно, там специально `std::cout << "Image has been captured" << std::endl;` и оно отрабатывает каждый раз

Comment: а код возврата там есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Достаточно было поменять путь к сохраняемым файлам по образцу 
`sprintf_s(filename, "test_%d.jpg", i)`

[Вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787015/cant-cat-image-from-the-videostream-opencv>)